# Calculate height of point on line in an elevation profile

Tags: qgis, elevation

I have a line of an elevation profile and a ground layer below it.

**Is there a possibility to get the height above ground for every position (not waypoint) on the line?**

My height profile in the built-in tool:
[image]
*The red doted lines are examples, where I would like to have height data above Ground*

In the real project, I have additional ground layers, so a solution where I can choose a specific ground layer would be great.

I am using QGIS 3.32.0-Lima

**EDITS**

I am searching for an automated way (e.g. hover on the line and see the height), I am aware of the measurement tool in the elevation profile window.

Here is a picture with 2 rasters and the waypoints (blue dots)
[image]

Comment: Is the line a vector layer? Does the line have Z values?

Comment: @BERA No, the line is just created by changing the style of the waypoints to become a line (in the height properties of the waypoints, set style to line).

Comment: But you do have some points (waypoints) with some Z values and you want to know the difference between the values expressed in the waypoint and the value of the raster at that location?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "every position on the line"?

Comment: @GBG yes, I have waypoints with z-values and to see the difference between the waypoints and the raster would also be great! I will add a picture, where the dots on the line are the waypoints.

Comment: @TomBrennan Basically, I wanted the ability to hover on the line and see the corresponding height difference between the line and the raster. However, I am also happy with just the difference between single waypoints and the height raster.

Comment: Use the Point Sampling Tool to populate the points with the values from the raster.  Use the raster calculator to populate a new attribute in the table with the difference between your points values and the raster values.  Use Map Tips to display those values.

Comment: @GBG Would it be possible, to show the differences in the hight profile itself somehow? Thanks for your help!